# Got Error when Implementing C# Tcp Hole Punching - Cannot Connect Behind NAT

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, nat

I have a server with public Ip Address and a client machine behind NAT which are implemented in C# language.
I've tried to program a tcp hole punching but got error when made socket from server to client. My steps are as below:

1) 1st, I make a socket connection to Public Server and send msg to it and started listening on port 17000

2) 2nd, Server got the msg and parse it

3) 3rd, I got the remoteEndPoint IpAddress & port number ( =Nat router Ip & Port ) on the server side

4) 4th try to connect to socket ( NAT Ip,Nat Port ) and send msg to client on port 17000 from server => means= I've made socket to nat router and Hope the router send my msg to client behind nat

But I've got the following error: 
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond X.X.X.X: 24352"

Could anyone help me how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your server behind a NAT?

Comment: No, My server has a valid & public ip address. I can connect to server from my machine which is behind NAT & send msg, but can not connect from server to my machine for sending msg.

Comment: So did you make the connection in step 1 from the same port that you are now listing on in step 4?

Comment: Actually, in step1, 1st I sent a msg by port 17000 from local machine to the server,then started listening on port 17000 to fetch msg from the server.

Comment: Sounds good. Post a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Btw, why does your server need to connect to the client? Can't the client just connect to the server?

Comment: how do you know that router is forwarding your request to client? when the server is trying to send message on NAT router? just a vague guess if you need to enable some port forwarding at router? or get some logs at router and see whats happening there?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is probably here:

> and Hope the router send my msg to client behind nat

Nat traversal (such as hole punching) depends on the implementation of the specific NAT. 
You assume that since the NAT saw a packet from the client's port 17000, and mapped it to some NAT port X, then it will forward all packets from port X back to the client. **NOT ALL NATs DO THAT!**

From [Microsoft Technet:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457011.aspx)

> The following types of NATs are defined:
>
> - Cone NATs: A NAT in which the NAT translation table entry stores a mapping between an internal address and port number and an external
>     address and port number. Once the NAT translation table entry is in
>     place, inbound traffic to the external address and port number from
>     any source address and port number is allowed and translated.
> - Restricted NATs: A NAT in which the NAT translation table entry stores a mapping between an internal address and port number and an
>     external address and port number, for either specific source addresses
>     or specific source address and port numbers. An inbound packet that
>     matches the NAT translation table entry for the external destination
>     address and port number from an unknown external address or port
>     number is silently discarded.
> - Symmetric NATs: A NAT that maps the same internal address and port number to different external addresses and ports, depending on the
>     external destination address (for outbound traffic).

Your hole punching approach will work for Cone and address restricted NATs. Not for port restricted NATs of symmetric NATs (which is probably the NAT in your case).

Comment: Tnx for your good answer.But, there is still a question: _" How can I solve my problem as you said I have faced with a symmetric NAT ? "_,and also I'm curious to know how do chat apps like viber, whatsapp send messages behind NAT devices ?

Comment: Well, the simplest approach is to have the app initiate a connection to the server (which isn't behind NAT), and keep that connection open all the time. Then, use that connection for all messaging (essentially relaying all messages through the server). So the simplest approach is just to avoid the whole problem by not writing a peer-to-peer application, but a client-server one.

Comment: Tnx for helping me. I let you know when I've solved my problem.